# Unable to process number 600851475143, but I can 13195 perfectly

Tags: c, types, floating-point, primes

Basically, I've been trying to complete the 3rd question on projecteuler.net. The example gives me the number 13195 which this program (writting in C) accurately returns a prime factor tree of 5 7 13 29, but when I input the question number 600851475143 nothing happens. I have also made a similar program in Python about a year ago and that solves the factor tree for 600851475143. I think it has to do with the data types I'm using but I can't find a reliable source for information on that and how to do modulo with floats/doubles/big thingies.

Thanks,

Clement

**Code:**

```
//
//  main.c
//  Project Euler Question 3
//
//  Created by Cwbh on 2/11/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Cwbh. All rights reserved.
//

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int is_prime(int x);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int pft[100];
    int number;
    int pointerloc = 0;

    printf("Enter the number to find the Prime Factor Tree of: ");
    scanf("%d", &number);

    if (is_prime(number) == 0) {
        for (int i = 2; i < number; i++) {
            if (number%i == 0 && is_prime(i) == 1) {
                pft[pointerloc] = i;
                pointerloc++;
            }
        }
    }else{
        printf("You've entered a prime number to begin with!");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < pointerloc; i++) {
        printf("%d\n",pft[i]);
    }


    return 0;
}

int is_prime(int x){
    int prime = 1;

    for (int i = 2; i < x; i++) {
        if (x%i == 0) {
            prime = 0;
            break;
        }
    }

    return prime;

}
```

Comment: When doing trial division, you only need to test to sqrt(number).  This will give you a big speed up.  Also your for( i < number ) loop does not need to call is_prime().  Because you divide from low to high, you will only find prime factors.  This changes your code from O(n^2) to O(n).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like `int` is a 32-bit type on your machine.  That means 600851475143 won't fit (the largest number representable in a 32 bit integer is 4294967295). Use a 64-bit type and you should be OK.  You can use `uint64_t` from `stdint.h`, or maybe your machine has a 64-bit `long` or `long long` type.

The `%` operator only works on integer types in C, so trying to use it for a `float` or `double` won't work.

Another option you have is to use a "big number" library of some kind.  You can certainly write your own simple one that will suffice for Project Euler problems at this level.

Comment: I am running 10.8.2 on a Sandy Bridge i7 so 64bit is definitely hardware supported, not sure if my compiler does 64 though, ill try this though thanks!

Comment: What compiler?  You almost *certainly* have a 64-bit type available to you.

Comment: @Clement: I'm guessing that 10.8.2 is OS X, in which case you've had `long long` available for over a decade, and the compiler generates 64-bit programs by default.

Comment: I can't accept it just yet, but after adding the `uint64_t` to the number variable and `%lld` for the input I have successfully found the answer. Only thing is that it was noticeably slower than my python variant which is surprising.

Sorry for the lack of knowledge, i've picked up C yesterday

Comment: If you're using `uint64_t`, you should use `%llu` for printing.  If it's slow, you're probably compiling unoptimized.  Try adding `-O3` (or `-O4` if you're using clang and want to get link-time optimizations) to your command line.

Comment: Not only does he have a 64-bit type, he would have a 128-bit integer type available if he really needed it.

Comment: @Stephen Canon - germain comment, but explaining how to get a 128 bit might be more helpful to a beginner.  If he continues euler questions he will need big integers.

Comment: @jimmcnamara `typedef unsigned int uint128_t __attribute__((mode(TI)));` is the magic incantation for GCC (the shortest one that I know of), but at that point it is worth questioning whether the Euler problems might not better be approached in a language with native bigints and a nice syntax for them.

Comment: With GCC only if the underlying hardware supports it.  It is not a given. Solaris 10 on SPARC64-VII mode on an M4000 does not.  Does OSX by default?  See: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html